# How to state with rdf/rdfs/owl that an instance of class is responsible for /related of to all instances of a class?

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, rdfs, turtle-rdf

I'm just wondering how I can express in RDF/RDFS that an instance is related to another class. I want to express that the instance of a class woman contributes to the reproduction of humans. (Maybe a stupid example, but I couldn't think of anything better ...). It would be modeled as follows:

```
<http://www.example.com/Human_C> <rdf:type> <rdfs:Class> .
<http://www.example.com/Woman_C> <rdf:type> <rdfs:Class> .
<http://www.example.com/Emily> <rdf:type> <http://www.example.com/Woman_C> .
<http://www.example.com/Emily> <http://www.example.com/produces> <http://www.example.com/Human_C> .
```

I have never seen anything like this before, so I am interested in your opinon if this makes sense and how I can express my previous intent (maybe by use of OWL)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean to express that if an entity produces humans then the entity is a woman?

Comment: @ValerioCocchi, no I just want to know, if these statements express what I want to express. Does the last tripple make any sense? I have never seen this before ...

Comment: It depends on what you want to say. As it is, the triple is saying that Emily produces humans, but it's saying nothing about women as a class, i.e. the could be another woman who does not produce humans.

Comment: @ValerioCocchi, thanks. I mainly was interested in the expression of the triple because I have never seen that a class is related to an instance in this way. On the second topic regarding the class woman: I agree, there are women that do not produce new humans. But, let us assume, it would be the case that every woman produces humans. Would it make sense to introduce a the relation between both classes? Is there any w3c document or another reliable resource where such an expression is modeled?

Comment: What I had in mind was actually the opposite: not every woman produces humans, but everyone who produces humans is a woman.
Basically, for a property <p>, if there is a triple "?s <p> ?o .", we can say that the ?s must belong to a class.
https://www.w3.org/2007/OWL/wiki/Syntax#Object_Property_Domain